# How to use a LDR to control and fan and LED ring and a timer

Tags: python, multithreading, timer, micropython

I have a LDR, 5v fan and a ws2812 LED ring. When the LDR sees light I want the fan to turn off and the LED to turn on. When the LDR doesn't see light I want the LED to turn off and the fan to turn on for 5 mins and then if the LDR doesn't see light for a day I want the fan to turn on for 5 mins. For testing purposes I don't want to use 5 mins and a day I would rather use seconds to do the testing to make sure it work and then change it to the other times. It has been a few years since I have done anything with a pi and this is the first time doing anything on a pi pico with micropython.

```
from machine import Pin, ADC
import utime
import machine
from ws2812b import ws2812b

num_leds = 8
pixels = ws2812b(num_leds, 0,0, delay=0)

relay = Pin(15, Pin.OUT)
ldr = ADC(Pin(28))

pixels.fill(0,0,0)
pixels.show()

relay.value(0)

def setOff():
    for i in range(num_leds):
        pixels.set_pixel(i,0,0,0)
        pixels.show()

def setWhite(brightness):
    for i in range(num_leds):
        pixels.set_pixel(i,255,255,255)
        pixels.show()
        
while True:
    reading = ldr.read_u16()
    print("Value: " , reading)
    utime.sleep(0.2)
    if reading < 10000:
        relay.value(0)
        setWhite(0)
        
    elif reading > 50000:
        relay.value(1)
        setOff()
```

I have tried schedule and interrupt but I don't think that is the right way to do things.

Comment: Can you tell us specifically what it is that isn't working? The code in your question looks as if it should turn the LEDs and relay on and off depending on the LDR value, assuming that your hardware connections are correct. There's nothing there that would implement your 'for 5 minutes' and 'for a day' requirements though.

Comment: You are correct it works, but I don't know how to get the 5 min and day requirements worked in to the code.

Answer (score 0):

After you turn your LEDs on, create a timer that will shut them off after the configured amount of time.

```
from machine import Timer
TIMEOUT = 60  # expressed in seconds
auto_off = Timer(0)
auto_off.init(period=TIMEOUT*1000, mode=Timer.ONE_SHOT, callback=setOff)
```